# Using multi-select along with dropdown triangle displayed in ui-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ui-select

Is there any way to keep dropdown triangle (▼) displayed for `multiple` mode of `ui-select`?

```
<div ui-select multiple ng-model="selectedItems" class="form-control">
    <div ui-select-match>
        <span>{{$item.name}}</span>
    </div>

    <div ui-select-choices repeat="item in availableItems" >
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I managed to steal the triangle from ordinary `ui-select`:

```
<i class="caret pull-right" ng-click="$select.toggle($event)"></i>
```

but having difficulties displaying it properly on the ordinary place to the right. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: show us a Minimal Verifiable Complete Example and we can help

Comment: It is already provided. Any person that would be able to help knows how to make it working. Everything is standard and straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach I worked out is a scalable background SVG image applied using this CSS:

```
.select2-search-field {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1em' height='1em' viewBox='0 0 13 6' fill='gray'><polygon points='0 1 8 1 4 5'></polygon></svg>");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-position-x: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I got so far: reused this `caret` class and made it displayed on top of the component using style `position: relative; left: -1.5em;`, placing the element right after `ui-select` (placing it straight inside `ui-select` is not possible because angularjs replaces it's content with own templates - so my `caret` comes after but then shifted left)

Also, I had to attach `ng-click` which does `$select.toggle($event)` to this `caret` element. As long as the `$select` is not available out of scope of `ui-select`, I had to introduce outer controller which includes both `ui-select` and `caret` elements - and simply assign `$select` a field within it using `ng-init` on `ui-select`.

So it looks something like:

```
<div ui-select multiple ng-model="selectedItems" class="form-control" ng-init="mySelect = $select">
    <div ui-select-match>
        <span>{{$item.name}}</span>
    </div>

    <div ui-select-choices repeat="item in availableItems" >
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>  
</div>

<span style="position: relative; left: -1.5em;" class="caret" 
ng-click="mySelect.toggle($event)></span>
```

▼ is displayed only when dropdown is not opened. Also, clicking it requires some pixel-hunting (can be mitigated by putting the `caret` into a div that spreads vertical). So it's a partial solution.